# Generic type parameters C# - How to generic class return type

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have two classes and both contain the same fields

```
Class A  
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Designaton { get; set; }
}

Class B 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Designation { get; set; }
}
```

And I have one interface and two classes which are inherited from interface

```
public interface IDeprt
{
    object BindData();
}
```

And two extractor classes:

```
public classAItem : IDeprt
{
    public object BindData()
    {
        return new A()
                   {
                       // mapping operation
                   }
    }
}

public classBItem : IDeprt
{
     public object BindData() 
     {
         return new B()
                    {
                         //same mapping operation
                    }
     }
 }
```

My question, how can I implement this in generic way using `<T>` .
Both classes are doing same operation only return type change. If I am doing in the above way there is lot of duplication of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `ITem` interface and also `BindData` generic make them use the same generic parameter.

```
public interface IItem<T>
{
   T BindData();
}
```

Then implement the subclasses like below :

```
public class AItem : ITem<A>
{
  public A BindData(){
    return new A(){
     // mapping operation
    }
  }
}


public class BItem : ITem<B>
{
    public B BindData(){
       return new B(){
         //same mapping operation
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : As the question evolves.

Make a shared base class for A and B classes.

```
public abstract class CommonItem 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public  int Designaton { get; set; }
}

class A : CommonItem 
{   
}

class B : CommonItem 
{   
}
```

Then make class with a method that accepts a generic parameter with `new` and `CommonItem` constraints.

```
public class Binder
{
    public T BindData<T>() where T: CommonItem, new()
    {
       return new T()
                  {
                       // you can access the properties defined in  ICommonItem
                  }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var binder = new Binder();
var boundA = binder.BindData<A>();
var boundB = binder.BindData<B>();
```

Comment: In the second approach , in Class A and Class B ,do I need to declare fields also because they have inherited from ICommonItemInterface?

Comment: And how do I call BinderClass. Do I need to pass Class A and Class B type ,Because output should be A and B return type

Comment: @Madhu added usage.

Comment: Thank you so much .Let me try.

Comment: Hi Eldar, One small help, in the first approach If I am declaring in any common file                           
       private read-only IEnumerable<IItem<T>> _items;                                               Here in T,it is giving error. How to declare this?

Comment: @Madhu can you update the question in order to reflect the issue you are having. I can't quite understand the above comment.

Comment: Sorry,I confused you. In your second approach, It is giving an error in Binder class near T. T could not be found. It is showing syntax error

Comment: @Madhu ah sorry it was a typo.

Comment: public class Binder
    {
        public T BindData<T>() where T : CommonItem, new()
        {
            return new T()
            {
                
                // you can access the properties defined in ICommonItem
            };
        }
    }

Comment: Yeah,I got it. I was just updating.Thank you so much